# Programatically creating DataSet and setting to DataGrid causing blank rows for the number of records that should be shown

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, dataset

I am working on a c# project and I am trying to create a DataSet and set the itemssource of a datagrid to the dataset.

However, when the grid loads, it shows 4 blank lines (4 records being inside the database) and none of the columns are being shown.

Below is the code for how I am calling the dataset creation function and assign it to the DataGrid.

```
private void loadData()
{
    Classes.SoftwareManager softwareManager = new Classes.SoftwareManager();
    DataSet dataSet = softwareManager.getDatasetForSoftware();
    if (dataSet != null)
    {
        softwareGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dataSet.Tables[0].Columns.RemoveAt(0);
        softwareGrid.ItemsSource = dataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    }
}
```

Below is the code that creates the dataset which is returned in the function above.

```
public DataSet getDatasetForSoftware()
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            DataColumn idCol = new DataColumn();
            DataColumn softwareCol = new DataColumn("Software Name");
            DataColumn serverCol = new DataColumn("DB Server");
            DataColumn userNameCol = new DataColumn("DB Username");
            DataColumn passwordCol = new DataColumn("DB Password");
            DataColumn portCol = new DataColumn("DB Port");
            DataColumn webInstallLocationCol = new DataColumn("Web Install Location");
            DataColumn softwareInstallLocationCol = new DataColumn("Software Install Location");
            DataColumn startScriptNameCol = new DataColumn("Start Script Name");
            DataColumn statusCol = new DataColumn("Status");

            idCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
            softwareCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            serverCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            userNameCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            passwordCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            portCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            webInstallLocationCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            softwareInstallLocationCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            startScriptNameCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            statusCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            table.Columns.Add(idCol);
            table.Columns.Add(softwareCol);
            table.Columns.Add(serverCol);
            table.Columns.Add(userNameCol);
            table.Columns.Add(passwordCol);
            table.Columns.Add(portCol);
            table.Columns.Add(webInstallLocationCol);
            table.Columns.Add(softwareInstallLocationCol);
            table.Columns.Add(startScriptNameCol);
            table.Columns.Add(statusCol);


            List<SoftwareDetails> softwareDetails = getSoftwareDetails();

            if (softwareDetails != null)
            {
                foreach (SoftwareDetails software in softwareDetails)
                {
                    DataRow dataRow = table.NewRow();
                    dataRow[idCol] = software.id;
                    dataRow[softwareCol] = software.softwareName;
                    dataRow[serverCol] = software.dbServer;
                    dataRow[userNameCol] = software.dbUsername;
                    dataRow[passwordCol] = software.dbPassword;
                    dataRow[portCol] = software.dbPort;
                    dataRow[webInstallLocationCol] = software.webInstallLocation;
                    dataRow[softwareInstallLocationCol] = software.softwareInstallLocation;
                    dataRow[startScriptNameCol] = software.startScriptName;
                    dataRow[statusCol] = software.status;
                    table.Rows.Add(dataRow);
                }
            }
            ds.Tables.Add(table);
            return ds;
        }
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: I see `softwareGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;` shouldn't be True?

Comment: Yea that was the reason. Could you make it an answer and I can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see `softwareGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;` If your grid does not contain column definition, you should set

```
softwareGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
```